# How do you Edit and Delete HTML table rows in Codeigniter Using Modals?

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

So I am making a web application wherein an admin can delete and deactivate user accounts. I retrieved the accounts in my database and placed them in a HTML table with corresponding "Delete" and "Deactivate" Buttons by using a foreach loop. However, I am having a hard time trying to figure out how I can delete or update these records by row. Currently, I'm trying to code the deactivate function only, which is basically just updating my "isActive" column in the database from "1" (active) to "0" (deactivated). Is it also right to place `<a href="<?php echo base_url()."admin_accounts/acc_deactivate?id=".$row->userid ?>">` in the modal? Thank you!

Modal - view_adminaccounts.php:

```
<?php foreach($users as $row): ?>
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete-modal" role="dialog">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="signin">
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                        <p> Are you sure you want to remove this user from the system? </p><br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-1">Yes</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="deactivate-modal" role="dialog">

        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="signin">
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                        <p> Are you sure you want to deactivate this user from the system? </p><br>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url()."admin_accounts/acc_deactivate?id=".$row->userid ?>"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom-1">Yes</button></a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Tables - view_adminaccounts.php:

```
         <table class="table table-hover" id="tracking-table">

                <tr>
                    <th><br>First Name</th>
                    <th><br>Last Name</th>
                    <th><br>User ID</th>
                    <th><br>Address</th>
                    <th><br>E-mail Address</th>
                    <th><br>Contact Number</th>
                    <th><br>Action</th>
                </tr>

                <?php foreach($users as $row): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row->firstname; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->lastname; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->userid; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->address; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->email; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row->contactnum; ?></td>
                    <td class="action-button">
                      <a href="admin-accounts-edit.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-custom-2">Edit</button></a>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom-3" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>  Delete </button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deactivate-modal"> Deactivate </button>
                    </td>

                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>


           </table>
```

Controller: admin_accounts.php

```
function acc_deactivate()
{
    if(isset($_GET['userid']))
    {
        $id=$_GET['userid'];
        $this->load->model('model_accounts');
        $this->model_accounts->deactivate($id);
        redirect('admin_accounts');
    }
}
```

Model: model_accounts.php

```
function deactivate() 
{
    $id=$_GET['userid'];
    $this->db->set('0', $isActive);
    $this->db->where('userid', $id);
    $this->db->update('accounts');
}
```

James' ID
[image: James' ID]

Marc's ID
[image: Marc's ID]

Comment: why you can not use the same way to delete?

Comment: for edit just get values and pop up form on the basis of id.

Comment: Right now, I am not coding the delete function. With regards to the edit function, my problem is that all records point to the same ID, in this case, id=2. It also doesn't update the values in the database. Please check the image above.